# How to create router for a component in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-component

How to create router file for a component of joomla. I am using Sef
url in particular

Comment: What you tried doing yourself?

Comment: I used jroute::_('index.php?option=com_abc&view=def&ghi=102') an Url of component view . But There is  SEF url is break after view  URL :mydomain.com/Sitename/abc/?view=def&ghi=102

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and after trawling through the internet and only ever coming across answers like the one seen here ("see the documentation") which is really unhelpful in my opinion and of all the documentation that page is the most unhelpful.

Anyway I firstly ended up giving up on the "component router", I could get it to easily work to build routes but found that it wouldn't parse anything and without having both working, it was pointless continuing.

In the end I decided going down the plugin path was the answer and found this really good plugin [here](http://danxuliu.users.sourceforge.net/files/joomla/simplecustomrouter.html#about) from Daniel Calviño Sánchez.

I then ended up finally coming across some [joomla documentation here](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_System_Plugin_to_augment_JRouter) that IS perfect and will get you exactly where you need to go.

I personally think that the joomla router needs alot of work and saw there are lots of ideas from people wanting it upgraded. I found using a plugin in the end was the easiest path and was the better solution all round.

I would be happy to discuss with anyone as to why my component router wouldn't call its parse method as if that actually worked, it would've been my first choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately documentation didn't provide a way to register my router so I found an alternative solution.

The router.php is actually a `Joomla\CMS\Router\SiteRouter`

You can use the `$this` variable, even if you think you're not within a class.

This can be checked by performing `var_dump($this)`

There are two methods that can be used.

```
$this->attachBuildRule(function(){
    // build rule code
});
$this->attachParseRule(function(){
   // parse rule code
});
```

If you are using an object implementing RouterInterface the callbacks are the following

```
$this->attachBuildRule([$myRouter, 'build']);
$this->attachParseRule([$myRouter, 'parse']);
```

The methods expect a callable and a STAGE, see `Router::PROCESS_*` constants in namespace `Joomla\CMS\Router`

If you are using PHPStorm you can write the following code for assistance:

```
/**
 * @var $this Joomla\CMS\Router\SiteRouter
*/
```

Comment: If you are able to provide support for Joomla questions, please join us at JoomlaStackExchange and see if you can help to resolve some of the unresolved questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) .

It describes very precisely how to create a Route and how the Routing works in Joomla.

Also check out  `com_content/router.php` as an example